# Remove 'always on top'

Tags: windows, winapi

I have create a window with no extended styles and WS_CAPTION with WS_SYSMENU as the dwStyle and the class is dialog box so the window is always on top of the window that created it, I'm wondering how I change that so the window that create the dialog can be on top and vice versa?

Comment: Putting a window on top of a dialog doesn't make much sense.  Such a window is disabled by the dialog to ensure it is modal, the user would have a pretty hard time getting back to the dialog window to resume using your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a dialog you pass a `hwndParent` parameter and this specifies the owner of the dialog box. Owned windows always appear on top of their owners.

If you pass `0` for the parent then the dialog won't have an owner at all, and will behave like a "normal" window.